# MapQuest points on a route

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, openstreetmap, direction, mapquest

I am using the MapQuest Android API and drawing a route between two points. What I am trying to do is find multiple points along the route, say the lat and long values every 100 meters along on the path and store it in an array. Is there a way to do that. I hope my question was clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reduce the number of points in a path, but still keep an accurate representation of the path, your best bet is to use a line-simplification algorithm.

A common line-simplification algorithm is Douglas-Peucker, and there is an implementation of Douglas-Peucker in the Google MyTracks project that you can use, licensed under Apache v2.0:
https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/util/LocationUtils.java#78

Here's the code, in case the link breaks:

```
/**
 * Decimates the given locations for a given zoom level. This uses a
 * Douglas-Peucker decimation algorithm.
 * 
 * @param tolerance in meters
 * @param locations input
 * @param decimated output
 */
private static void decimate(double tolerance, ArrayList<Location> locations, ArrayList<Location> decimated) {
  final int n = locations.size();
  if (n < 1) {
    return;
  }
  int idx;
  int maxIdx = 0;
  Stack<int[]> stack = new Stack<int[]>();
  double[] dists = new double[n];
  dists[0] = 1;
  dists[n - 1] = 1;
  double maxDist;
  double dist = 0.0;
  int[] current;

  if (n > 2) {
    int[] stackVal = new int[] { 0, (n - 1) };
    stack.push(stackVal);
    while (stack.size() > 0) {
      current = stack.pop();
      maxDist = 0;
      for (idx = current[0] + 1; idx < current[1]; ++idx) {
        dist = LocationUtils.distance(
            locations.get(idx), locations.get(current[0]), locations.get(current[1]));
        if (dist > maxDist) {
          maxDist = dist;
          maxIdx = idx;
        }
      }
      if (maxDist > tolerance) {
        dists[maxIdx] = maxDist;
        int[] stackValCurMax = { current[0], maxIdx };
        stack.push(stackValCurMax);
        int[] stackValMaxCur = { maxIdx, current[1] };
        stack.push(stackValMaxCur);
      }
    }
  }

  int i = 0;
  idx = 0;
  decimated.clear();
  for (Location l : locations) {
    if (dists[idx] != 0) {
      decimated.add(l);
      i++;
    }
    idx++;
  }
  Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Decimating " + n + " points to " + i + " w/ tolerance = " + tolerance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in Java and Actionscript.

Firstly, if you were not already aware, each leg in the route you have is a straight line.  The straighter the route, the less legs you will have.

To identify points of an equal distance along the route - or in my case, travel time along the route - simply cycle through the set of [lat,long] coords calculating the cumulative distance at the end of each leg.

Using this information you can easily modify your loop to check where a distance point (or points) occur along a leg. Remembering that each leg is a straight line. If so, its simple enough to identify the distance along the leg you are looking for and from that calculate the point that is that far along the leg.

For this you need 2 algorithms:

1. the distance between 2 [lat,lng] coordinates
2. the point that is x distance along a line between 2 [lat, lng] coordinates

Easier said than done, these are complex algorithms and there are some dubious examples on the net. Few in my opinion do a good job in explaining how the math works, and mot I have found are incomplete.

Then I found this gem: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I implemented my algorithms in actionscript and java based on this excellent reference by Chris Veness.

The link should provide everything you need. Explanation of what you need to do, concise algorithms in both psudocode and javascript, and if thats not enough, a facility to test your algorithms.